# Magento 2 - Suddenly can't login into backend

Tags: magento2, admin, login, backend

I cant login to the backend anymore suddenly even though I made no changes.

So I tried to created a new admin user via CLI but I get **No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run**

Other users of my team still can login.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the **No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run** error.

For me the problem was that the Admin role in the table `authorization_role` was set to "Administrator" instead of "Administrators".

So I changed it directly in the database and now I can create admins from the CLI again.